# Why is the file not creating when trying to copy SQLite database from asset to phone memory?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, greendao

I am using GreenDAO as ORM and using a pre-populated database which is encrypted by SQLite Cipher. Encryption is the feature of GreenDAO. So when a user launches the application I am using below code to copy the database from asset to phone memory.

```
    ContextWrapper cw =new ContextWrapper(context);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        DB_PATH = cw.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";  
    } else {
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    OutputStream myOutput = null;
    int length;
    InputStream myInput = null;
    try
    {
        myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        myOutput =new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH+ DB_NAME);
        while((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.close();
        myOutput.flush();
        myInput.close();
```

But on some device, it is showing following error

"Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.appname/databases/my-db.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) "

and according to firebase crash report the below line is responsible for the error.

```
myOutput =new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH+ DB_NAME);
```

How can I solve this and can ensure that the database will work in all device. However I am using below code to check database exist or not

```
        File file = new File(DB_PATH+ DB_NAME);
        if(file.exists()) {
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory

```
/data/user/0/com.example.appname/databases
```

does not exist yet.

Before you try to write a file in it check if the directory exists and if not create it.

```
if(file.getParentFile().exists()) 
    if(!file.getParentFile().mkdirs())
         return false.
```